# Experience Manger invoke call lag for non-administrator

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1-hr1, performance

When launching Experience Manager as a non-administrator, there is a page invoke call that takes a nearly five minutes to respond.

[image: Non Admin Network Trace]
But when launching as an admin, the same call executes in less than ten seconds.

[image: Admin Network Trace]

the two invoke calls have the same response, with the exception of the admin functions of UAG. Any help is appricated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue at a client where there were a lot of groups and a lot of publications. When logging into the CM, if a regular user it would take 15 minutes to log in, but admins would be instant.  The issue was due to how the CM checks which group a user belongs to and what publications and folders he has access to. It's basically a very long nested loop algorithm.  The way this issue was solved was by contacting product support and they developed a custom hotfix for that customer's scenario. Perhaps a similar condition exists in your system.

Comment: Issue resolved in Web 8.5 for us. SDL must have included the hotfix.